# Automapper Complex mapping from List to Object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have object structure as below

```
public class Source
{
    public Connection Connection { get; set;}
}

public class Connection
{
    public string Id { get; set;
    public IEnumerable<Distributor> Distributors { get; set;
}

public class Distributor { get; set; }
{
    public DistributorType Type {get; set;}
    public  string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
     public Distribution Distribution { get; set;
}

public class Distribution
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public  string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map the Source to Destination for the property Distribution. The mapping is as below

```
Source.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault().X => Destination.Distribution.X
Source.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault().Y => Destination.Distribution.Y
Source.Connection.Id => Destination.Distribution.Id
```

I have tried using the Custom Resolver but no luck

```
public class CustomDistributorResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, Distribution >
    {
        public Distribution  Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, Distribution destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var result = source.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DistributorType =="ABC");
            if (result == null) return null;

            return new Distribution 
            {
                Id                      = source.Connection?.Id,
                X                       = result.X,
                Y                       = result.Y
            };
        }
    }
```

### Mapping Pofile

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Distribution, opt => opt.MapFrom( new CustomDistributorResolver()));
```

I always get Distribution value as NULL.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here on mapping.

-Alan-

Comment: I'm not near my windows PC right now but I had something similar which I think was down to the lazy loading settings in EF core. it might be worth checking that.

Comment: `ForMember(d => d.Distribution, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DistributorType =="ABC"))`

Answer (score -1):

I am not very sure what you will deal with the IEnumerable. So I use linq to approach.

```
var id = Source.Connection.Id;
var distributions = Source.Connection.Distributors.Select(m=> new Distribution()
                    {
                            Id = id,
                            X = m.X,
                            Y = m.Y,
                    });
```

Automapper would like :

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Distribution.Id ,opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Connection.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Distribution.X,  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault().X))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Distribution.Y,  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault().Y));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a type converter

```
private class DestinationConverter : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
{
    public Destination Convert(Source source,
    Destination destination,

    ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var result = source.Connection.Distributors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "ABC");

        if (result == null) return null;
        destination = new Destination();

        destination.Distribution = new Distribution
        {
            Id = source.Connection?.Id,
            X = result.X,
            Y = result.Y
        };

        return destination;
    }
}
```

and register the converter

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing<DestinationConverter>();
```

Comment: I know it's manual mapping, but i think that it's the only possible solution for this case due to the FirstOrDefault research. The author mentioned CustomDistributorResolver, so I try a possible solution with another kind of mapping.

Comment: No, it's not. As I've commented above, you can put that query in a `MapFrom`. And probably pass the `Id` in `context.Items`.

Comment: Sorry, one more time -:). The property Id in Distribution is source.Connection?.Id. With your solution Id isn't mapped, because not exist in Distributor. The result have X and Y from a class(Distributor) and ID from one another(Connection).

Comment: I've already covered that. Yet another option is to map from `source.Connection`.